# Mongoose connections count to MongoDB Atlas after reconnect

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We have the following problem: 7 servers connect to MongoDB Atlas, considering connection pool the amount of connections MongoDB shows (minus all service connections from clusters, backup, loggers, etc) is 35. which is OK: 7 servers with 5 connections each. But then suddenly MongoDB was restarted (don't know why, some internal thing, I guess) and connections became like 100+ for every server. so if in the beginning it was 35, now it's 900+. Previous connections seem to stay hanging somewhere. The code:

```
const RECONNECT_TIMEOUT = 5000;

mongoose.Promise = Promise; //  Set mongoose to use ES6 Promises.
const db = mongoose.connection;

const connect = () => {
    mongoose
        .connect(DB, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            autoReconnect: true,
            reconnectInterval: 1000,
            reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
            poolSize: 5
        })
        .catch(() => {
            //  No further treatment required: Connection events are already doing this
        });
};
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
    db.on('error', err => {
        logger.error(`MongoDB connection error:\n`, err);
    });

    db.on('connected', () => {
        logger.info('Connected to MongoDB');
    });

    db.once('open', () => {
        logger.info('MongoDB connection opened');
    });

    db.on('reconnected', () => {
        logger.info('MongoDB reconnected');
    });

    db.on('disconnected', () => {
        void db.close();
        void mongoose.disconnect(() => {
            logger.error(`MongoDB disconnected. Reconnecting in ${RECONNECT_TIMEOUT / 1000} s...`);
            setTimeout(() => connect(), RECONNECT_TIMEOUT);
        });
    });
}

connect();
```

I've recreated the problem this way: run server locally, it connects and establishes some amount of connections (pool size is 5, also by default). Then I just disable and enable network adapter. Then I see amount of connections with this query to admin db:
`const connections = (await db.command({ currentOp: 1, $all: 1 })).inprog;`

First, before server starts, I have 1 active connection when I do this request (which is OK).
Then, when server connects, I see 6 connections (1 for query and 5 for pool - this is OK).
Then, after I restarted network adapter I see how amount of connections starts to raise: 10, 17, 26, 33... they start to accumulate somewhere and if locally I see - after some time - connections amount is reduced a little by itself, but connections from our servers to MongoDB in Atlas cloud stays 900+ for more then 24 hours already.

Why this many connections and can this behavior be fixed? Is something wrong with how we connect to MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Read the mongod/mongos logs to see which driver and client host/IP are making connections.

Enable query logging to see what queries are being sent.

Use currentOp etc. to see what is happening on the server.

Comment: In case of local recreation of the problem I know what host/IP making connections. 
Query logging with mongoose shows only create indexes queries on connection. After reconnect - silence. CurrentOp is exactly what I used to see amount of connections, I made assumption that something is wrong based on results of currentOp query (which is also provided in my question)

Comment: I do not quite understand the purpose of your comment. You need specifics to debug this situation, which I see neither in the comment nor in the question. For example, complete server log and currentOp output.